# Increment an "ID" count without a object with a starting value (java)

Tags: java, counter

Everytime I run this program to create a new object it is supposed to start at 1000 and each time it is created increment by one. How do I increment the count of this independant of the count of the array.

Right now each time i run the program it outputs an Id of 1000 for each

Please be as simple as possible I don't understand java that well. thanks

Main program

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

 public class useConcert {

 private static Concert[] concert = new Concert[100];
   private static int numConcert = 0;

 public static void main (String[] args){
  String userInput  = "";
  boolean testResult; 

  do {

        userInput = mainMenu();

        if (userInput.equals("1")) {
       do{
          String artist = getStringInput("Artist or Group name?");
          int month = getIntegerInput("Enter month in XX format ");
          int day = getIntegerInput("Enter day in XX format ");
          int year = getIntegerInput("Enter year in XXXX format");
          int ticketCost = getIntegerInput("Enter cost per ticket ($25 - $250)");
          int quantTickets = getIntegerInput("Enter Number of tickets available (Max 10,000)");  
          int concertId = 1000;    
          concert[numConcert++] = new Concert(artist,quantTickets,ticketCost,month,day,year,concertId);
       }while (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Add another concert?")==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
        } else if (userInput.equals("2")) {
        listConcert();
        } 
    } while (!userInput.equals("0"));


  public static String concertList(){
     String outputString = "";
     for (int idx =0;  idx < numConcert; idx++){
        outputString += concert[idx].shortString() + "\n";
     }
     return outputString;
   }  

   public static void listConcert() {
     EZJ.dialog(concertList());
   }
  }
```

Class

```
public class Concert {
 private String artist = "";
 private int quantTickets = 0;
 private int ticketCost = 0;
 private int month = 0;
 private int day = 0;
 private int year = 0;
 private int numConcert = 0;
 private int concertId = 1000;

 public Concert(String artist, int quantTickets, int ticketCost, int month, int day, int year, int concertId){
  this.artist = artist;
  this.quantTickets = quantTickets;
  this.ticketCost = ticketCost;
  this.month = month;
  this.day = day;
  this.year = year;
  this.concertId = concertId;
 } 

 public void setConcertId (int concertId){
       concertId++;
     this.concertId = concertId;
    }

public String shortString(){
    return " " + artist + " " + getConcertId();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to keep the concert ID separate from the array count. In fact, the array count would be a very good concert ID. You would just have to modify this line to read:

```
concert[numConcert++] = new Concert(artist, quantTickets, ticketCost, month, day, year, numConcert);
```

Comment: You would use this even if you have to in the future be able to search by concert id?

Comment: Actually, at this point I am thinking that there is no need for a concert ID. If you need it, you can just use the array index.

Comment: But then how do you start the array index at 1000?

Comment: First, make the array able to hold 1000 elements. Second, change the `numConcert` variable to be 1000 at the beginning. Third, change this line to use `numConcert--` instead of `numConcert++`. But be warned: In the future, if you continue developing this way, you will run out of room in your array and get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I advise you to learn about array lists, so you can prevent this problem from happening.

Comment: You can also just increment your concertID: `concert[numConcert++] = new Concert(artist, quantTickets, ticketCost, month, day, year, concertId++);`

Comment: That is not what I need , I need the concert class to start at 1000 and each time i make a new one "add concert" it needs to increase to 1001 and so on. Woun't using that method then assign each one to 1000 then 999 then 998 and so on I think radiodef got it

Comment: sadly I just tested it like so and it still outputs 1000 for each

Comment: I can't devote much more energy to this right now, but I hope to come back and figure out what is going on.